# Слова, составленные из букв А, О, У

Tags: c++, системы-счисления

Все 5-буквенные слова, составленные из букв А, О, У, записаны в алфавитном порядке.
Вот начало списка:

1. ААААА
2. ААААО
3. ААААУ
4. АААОА ……

Запишите слово, которое стоит на 240-м месте от начала списка.

Comment: с трудом припоминаю информатику, но у вас простое преобразование в троичную систему счисления числа 240....
пы.сы. ответ: YYYYA

Comment: Нет, ответ YYYOA, так как отсчёт нужно начинать с нуля, а не с одного.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что-то типа этого:

```
char str[6]={0};
char chars[3]={'A', 'O', 'Y'}; //Для перевода троичных цифр в буквы
int a;
cin >> a;
a--; //В коде отсчёт идёт с нуля, а не с единицы, как по условию задачи

//Переводим в троичную систему делением на 3 и записыванием остатка в обратном порядке
for(int pos=4; pos>=0; pos--)
{
    str[pos]=chars[a%3];
    a/=3;
}
cout << str;
```

Comment: А поподробнее?

Comment: Добавил комментарии в код.